# Possible tray icon sizes across different OS

Tags: java, swing, tray

When putting application in to system tray, I can find that particular OS tray size like this:

```
if (SystemTray.isSupported()) {
     SystemTray tray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();
     Dimension trayIconSize = tray.getTrayIconSize();
}
```

Now I can resize some image to specified size - but it will not look as good as original image (not resized).

I'm thinking to create various sizes pictures, and select one according system tray. But there is another question - what are possible system tray sizes across different OS? I'm thinking about 16,24,32,64 px. Is it enough?